# Spring boot version upgrade causes Url's slashes escaped with backslash

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-thymeleaf

I upgraded my project from **JDK 8** to **JDK 11** and spring boot version from **'1.5.12. Release'**  to **'2.7.12'**. Project uses Thyme leaf for UI template.

Spring boot dependencies pulls down all the compatible versions it requires, **e.g. Spring-core 5.3.27, spring-web 5.3.27, spring-webmvc 5.3.27.**

My controller method returns Modal and View object. Inside the controller, Modal View object adds an object `eg mv.addObject("targetUrl","http://example.com/test/part1/part2?token=bxz")`

View is an HTML file that contains a JavaScript where target URL object is assigned to a variable `eg var targetUrl =  /*[[${targetUrl}]]*/ 'value';`

I am asserting in the unit test case that Response Body contains the HTML file content, where the URL contains `http://example.com/test/part1/part2?token=bxz` .

After the upgrade to spring boot higher version, the URL comes as

```
http:\/\/example.com\/test\/part1\/part2?token=bxz
```

I copied the above URL in browser and press the enter key, the URL opens the home page instead of the intended page as it converts `http:\/\/example.com\/test\/part1\/part2?token=bxz` to http://example.com//test//part1//part2?token=bxz

I tried downgrading spring boot to the lowest version 2.6.0 that is compatible with jdk11, still it did not help. Furthermore, I found during debugging when a Model View object is returned, the target URL has not escaped yet.

Any idea/suggestions how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.